# Force all users in MU to change their passwords

Tags: password, reset

I'm looking for a solution to notify/force all users in an MU network to change their passwords. Any ideas of a solution out there as a plug-in?

Comment: Found solution: PassExpire is a WordPress plugin. All set for now.

Comment: Again - please add your solution as an answer, so the question doesn't haunt us all as unanswered. TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PassExpire](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/expire-password/) force all users to change password at next login. Or set it to expires user passwords after 60 (Variable) days and requires a password change on login.

Note: This is community wiki answer for this Question (as @tony-zeoli has already answered his own question).

Comment: Pass Expire isn't working for me on WP network. I contacted Dylan, the developer. He had a family emergency and wasn't able to update the plug-in or look at it as of about a week ago. I woudldn't recommend it at this point for a network, until it's stable on the developers end.